# React Component "closing" when lost focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/js/select2/core.js) style component in React.

I have got 90% functionality down, the one bit I just can't fathom is [hiding the result box when the user clicks away](https://i.imgur.com/7cFzixU.gifv)

The render method is:

```
render() {
    let resultBlock;

    if (this.state.showSearch) {
        resultBlock = (
            <div className="search-input-container" onBlur={this.onBlur}>
                <div className="search-input-results">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name={this.props.name}
                        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={this.inputKeyUp}
                        autoComplete="false" />
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i} data-value={item.id} onClick={this.itemSelected} className={item.isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}>{item.text}</li>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    let displayBlock;
    if (this.props.value.text) {
        displayBlock = this.props.value.text;
    } else {
        displayBlock = <span className="placeholder">{this.props.placeholder}</span>;
    }

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.label}:</label>

            <div className="form-input">
                <div className="searchable-dropdown" onClick={this.revealSearch}>
                    {displayBlock}
                    <div className="arrow"><i className="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true" /></div>
                </div>
                {resultBlock}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've tried moving `onBlur={this.onBlur}` around, but it only fires if the `<input...` had focus before one clicked away.

It can't be that complicated, the only approach I thought of, is attaching a global click handler to the page, and diff'ing clicks to understand if a user hasn't clicked on my component. But this seems over engineered.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: *"attaching a global click handler to the page"* - this is exactly how it should be done.

Comment: you serious?! right.... to what object, window, document?

Comment: @CallumLinington, window would work

Comment: Can I use `event.preventDefault()` in the window click handler to stop unwanted clicks? I should also detach the event, this should be done in componentWillUnmount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved this functionality by:

Putting this in the constructor:

```
this.windowClick = this.windowClick.bind(this);
```

(From what dfsq said) Put this in componentDidMount:

```
if (window) {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.windowClick, false);
}
```

This event handler:

```
windowClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.target.classList.contains('searchable-marker')) {
        return;
    } else {
        this.setState({
            showSearch: false
        });
    }
}
```

Where `searchable-marker` is just a class I put on all the div's, ul's, li's and inputs to make sure that if I clicked one of these, it wouldn't close the the box.

Adding the unmount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.windowClick, false);
}
```

Comment: You are thinking in right direction. It's better to bind click event in `componentDidMount`. Also `event.preventDefault()` seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

what you can try doing is onBlur you could change the value of this.state.showSearch = false and when this condition is satisfied add a className="hide" (hide{display: none}) by creating a custom function which returns a classname as a string.

Comment: That wouldn't quite cut it